# request data from API with Bearer token

Tags: python, bearer-token

I am still a beginner at web scraping,
I am trying to extract data from an API but the problem is that it has a Bearer token and this token changed after 5 to 6 hours so I have to go to the web page again and copy the token again
so is there any way to extract the data without any more opening to the web page and copy the token again

```
import json
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep


def make_request():
    headers = {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJMdXRiZlZRUVZhWlpmNTNJbGxhaXFDY3BCVTNyaGtqZiIsInN1YiI6MzEzMTcwLCJleHAiOjE2MjQzMjU2NDcsInJvbCI6ImRpc3BhdGNoZXIiLCJyb2xlcyI6WyJodXJyaWVyLmRpc3BhdGNoZXIiLCJjb2QuY29kX21hbmFnZXIiXSwibmFtIjoiRXNsYW0gWmVmdGF3eSIsImVtYSI6ImV6ZWZ0YXd5QHRhbGFiYXQuY29tIiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJlemVmdGF3eUB0YWxhYmF0LmNvbSIsImNvdW50cmllcyI6WyJrdyIsImJoIiwicWEiLCJhZSIsImVnIiwib20iLCJqbyIsInEyIiwiazMiXX0.XYykBij-jaiIS_2tdqKFIfYGfw0uS0rKmcOTSHor8Nk',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Origin': 'url',
        'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
        'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
        'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
        'Referer': 'url',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar-EG;q=0.8,ar;q=0.7',
        'dnt': '1',
    }

    
    data = {
        'status': 'picked'
    }
    response = requests.post('url/api', headers=headers, json=data)
    print(response.text)

    return json.loads(response.text)


def extract_data(row):
    data_row = {
        'order_id': row['order']['code'],
        'deedline': row['order']['deadline'].split('.')[0],
        'picked_at': row['picked_at'].split('.')[0],
        'picked_by': row['picked_by'],
        'processed_at': row['processed_at'],
        'type': row['type']
    }
    return data_row



def periodique_extract(delay):
    extract_count = 0
    while True:
        extract_count += 1
        data = make_request()
        if extract_count == 1 :
            df = pd.DataFrame([extract_data(row) for row in data['data']])
            df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\di\Desktop\New folder\a.csv", mode='a')
        else:
            df = pd.DataFrame([extract_data(row) for row in data['data']])
            df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\di\Desktop\New folder\a.csv", mode='a',header=False)
        print('exracting data {} times'.format(extract_count))
        sleep(delay)


periodique_extract(60)

#note: as the website is track live operation so I extract data every 1 min
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more about token, is it changed or expired after every 5-6 hours? your question is not clear, can you elaborate how the token is generated in first place? Your service may have refresh_token, use that to get new token without going back to your website.

Comment: you mean like that :     Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 177
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: dhh_token=; refresh_token=; _hurrier_session=81556f54bf555a952d1a7f780766b028
dnt: 1      ,,, if yes how can I use it

Comment: i found this info could you tell me the way Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 177 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Cookie: dhh_token=; refresh_token=; _hurrier_session=81556f54bf555a952d1a7f780766b028 dnt: 1